# What does idx mean or do in this contract?

Tags: solidity

Here is a contract from https://www.etherchain.org/account/0xc18a451d4ef2a85e7bf8404131c5f994a98bdb15#code

What exactly does `idx` mean or do?

```
    function enter() {
    if (msg.value < 500 finney) {
        msg.sender.send(msg.value);
        return;
    }

    // add a new participant to array
    uint idx = participants.length;
    participants.length += 1;
    participants[idx].etherAddress = msg.sender;
    participants[idx].amount = msg.value;

    // collect fees and update contract balance
    if (idx != 0) {
        collectedFees += msg.value / 10;
        balance += msg.value;
    } 
    else {
        //code 
    }
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, please don't forget to accept it as the correct answer by clicking the tick sign below voting arrows. This applies to all of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `uint idx = participants.length;` gets the length of the array and `participants.length += 1;` this one adds 1 to it. Finally `participants[idx]` adds a new key to the array and assign new `participants` to it.

An alternative will be a simple [`push`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#push-for-dynamic-storage-arrays) and [this #83](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/83) might be the reason why the coder avoid push

Comment: Is idx just the name of the variable?

Comment: @Vesa, yes :) `uint idx = participants.length;`